# PHP False return even after it is true

Tags: php

Below is my index.php file source code:

```
<?php
include "app/global.php";

$page = $_GET['page'];
echo $page;
?>
```

My app/global.php:

```
<?php
global $url;
$url = 'localhost/tpl';
$theme = 'default';

include 'classes/class.template.php';
$tpl = new Template($url, $theme);
?>
```

My class.template.php:

```
<?php
class Template {
    public function __construct($url, $theme) {
        if(file_exists($url . '/app/themes/' . $theme . '/header.php')) {
            include $url . '/app/themes/' . $theme . '/header.php';
        } else {
            echo "File not found!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So my problem is, if I am trying to check if the file exists, the location is:

```
http://localhost/tpl/app/themes/default/header.php
```

When I access it with a link it works, but it returns false when I try to check it with PHP. What do you think could be the solution for this?

Comment: Path should not begin with "localhost" in `$url = 'localhost/tpl';`

Comment: You're confusing URLs with filesystem paths `http://localhost/tpl/app/themes/default/header.php` !== `localhost/tpl/app/themes/default/header.php` !== `tpl/app/themes/default/header.php`

Comment: `file_exists('localhost/directory/filename.php');` will return false, because it's not a valid path. Also if you add http, it will be threatened as third party request for file exists. You have to check with either full path i.e. `/home/user/vhosts/myproject/tpl/app/themese/default/header.php`

Comment: Just a tip: be careful that people aren't able to access files you don't want to them access. For example, consider something like `example.com?page=../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The location was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You do not want to include a *URL*! You will want to include a *local file*. `http://localhost/tpl/app/themes/default/header.php` may be a URL via which the file can be accessed via HTTP, but you want to use the file path *on disk* instead. For example

```
/var/www/tpl/app/themes/default/header.php
```

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` is the hostname, not part of the path, therefore you shouldn't include it in `$url`.

Answer (score -2):

file_exists works for absolute path. You have written url. It must be something like "D:/wamp/www/your_project/your_file"

Comment: You can use relative paths.

Comment: What is wroing in my answer ? Url is not possible for file_exists. Please read it first

Comment: DONOT hardcode the drive info. this is absolute path which fails and makes it tightly coupled with the system.